# How to install Microsoft Teams via pacman for arch linux?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

**How to install Microsoft Teams via pacman for arch linux?**

Microsoft Teams is also available for linux. I have problems to get an easy installation for arch. Teams is not listed in official package manager for pacman?

I found only DEB and RPM for official download packages from Microsoft:
https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/download-app

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**a) using makepg and install package**

1. Clone teams arch git repository (PKGBUILD)

   ```
   git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/teams.git .
   ```
2. Build package using `makepkg` and install using -si option

   ```
   makepkg -si
   ```

See also:
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/teams/

**b) alternatively use yay as package manager to easy install aur packages**

1. if yay not installed

   ```
   git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
   cd yay
   makepkg -si
   ```
2. Use yay to install aur package

   `yay -S teams`

Comment: yay is also available via pacman.
try: "sudo pacman -Ss yay" to search
and "sudo pacman -Sy yay" to install yay

Comment: Hi! I installed the app but when I am trying to login, and I am greeted with "You're not on Teams yet, but you can set it up for your organization.". What am I doing wrong?? – Andy95 31 secs ago

Comment: @GurdeepSinghSidhu Are you sure about that? `yay` is not available through pacman for me.

Comment: yay was available when I used "sudo pacman -Syu" and "sudo pacman -S yay" on Manjaro

Comment: I did this and when I ran teams it brings up a dialogue with a message *"This version of Teams only supports work or school accounts managed by an organisation."* There's a button which says "Switch Teams app" which takes you to a web interface for teams if you click it. I wish someone would clarify this and provide an open Teams app if possible. I'm pretty sure I used to use Teams without an organisation before.

Answer (score 6):

Posting this as an answer though it is really an addendum to @SmaMa post.

As at 3/3/2022 the **AUR** package is broken on **Linux archi7 5.16.11-arch1-1** but the fix is

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/548771/teams-fails-to-load-on-linux.html

**Courtesy of MichaelN-3933**

Edit /usr/bin/teams and modify the line:

```
nohup "$TEAMS_PATH" "$@" --disable-namespace-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox > "$TEAMS_LOGS/teams-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```

to include the new option --disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox:

```
nohup "$TEAMS_PATH" "$@" --disable-seccomp-filter-sandbox --disable-namespace-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox > "$TEAMS_LOGS/teams-startup.log" 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 4):

Just run the following commands

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/teams.git
cd teams
makepkg -si
```

ms teams will be installed.

Answer (score 3):

`snap install teams` also works.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying `teams-for-linux` from AUR (reference https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/teams-for-linux) and I've been getting an error in the installation. The error was about couldn't solve some dependencies.

I solved this by commenting (adding a `#` at the beginning of the line) the `makedepends`. Through the installation process via `makepkg -si` I've been asked to choose between three node versions, but my already-installed node version satisfies the constraints of the package. Commenting it out and running `makepk -si` has installed successfully.

I picked `teams-for-linux` because the official `teams` does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed with `yay -S teams` and got some crippled beta preview that doesn't even work. It redirected me to the web version which doesn't work in Firefox. (only chrome/edge are supported).